# Could not locate device support files

Tags: xcode, appletv

I'm trying to run tvos app on my device which is running tvOS 12.3 using XCode 10.1 . It is showing the folllowing error -

> This Applice TV(4th generation) is running tvOS 12.3(16M154), which
>   may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I download the latest Xcode 10.2.1 and tried to locate Device Support files by right clicking Xcode and choose **show package content** and navigate to **Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/DeviceSupport** but didn't find any files that supports tvOS 12.3(16M154)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my previous "reply" got deleted by a moderator, I try to be as short and precise as possible this time.

**You can download the fitting device files from the link below.**

https://github.com/filsv/TVOSDeviceSupport

tvOS 12.3 and 13.0 got added now, so the most up to date device files are for tvOS 13.0 there.

Download and then copy the files to the desired folder.

Comment: You previous reply probably was deleted because it was considered a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested another solution and it works.

Rightclick Xcode -> Show Paket Content -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> AppleTVOS.platform -> DeviceSupport

At that location simply create the folder 12.3 and copy the content from 12.2 to it.
Done.

Xcode will keep saying *"Apple TV is busy, Xcode will continue when AppleTV is ready"*, but you can read the logs, take screenshots and most important enable the HUD.

p.s.

The Developer Mode stays activated, even if you close Xcode and turn of your Mac and your Apple TV.
afaik DevMode should only stay active when connected to Xcode ?